# Selenium : clicking on the biggest number to display the whole table

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I work on a table with more than two hundred rows.

They are displayed 10 by 10.

There is a button which can display 10, 20, 50, 100 or 200 rows at the same time.

I want Selenium WebDriver to click on the biggest number to display the whole table.

Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Yes, and if you'll show us your attempt at it, and also some HTML code, we can probably help you.

Comment: Can you share what you did so far? Any ideas how to do it, realization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to my question.
I just had to add last() at the end of my xpath to choose from the last element of my list.

`(//*[@id=\"suivis-container\"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/span[2]/span/ul)/*[last()]`